# Referencing a control inside a XSL Template from code behind?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom NewItem.aspx that I made by creating a new aspx from the exisiting one

I wanted to put a control in a row inside the XSL Template like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSectors" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',ddlSectors,'SelectedValue','TextChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Sector')}">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                        <!--<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Sector" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Sector')}"/>-->
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff7description{$Pos}" FieldName="Sector" ControlMode="New"/>
```

Now I want to reference ddlSectors from my code library but it always throws an object reference not set to an instatnce of an object.

I believe that this is becuase the control is inside the XSL template.

so is there any workaround for this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question: Is that dropdownlist rendered on each row?

But you could try referencing parent control and using [Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method to get that control.

However if you don't know exactly which control could be parent, you can write custom FindControlRecursive method to search for that control no matter where.

```
using System.Web.UI;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        public static T FindControlRecursive<T>(this Control parentControl, string id) where T : Control
        {
            T ctrl = default(T);

            if ((parentControl is T) && (parentControl.ID == id))
                return (T)parentControl;

            foreach (Control c in parentControl.Controls)
            {
                ctrl = c.FindControlRecursive<T>(id);

                if (ctrl != null)
                    break;
            }
            return ctrl;
        }
}
```

Then just call `FindControlRecursive<DropDownList>("ddlSectors")`.

Comment: Hi
this is not inside a gridview or something
this is inside a custom NewItem.aspx form

so the dropdownlist is rendered just once in a single html row.

I need to reference it from code behind.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Janis

your Idea inspired me.

but here is the function that worked for me

```
Control FindControl2(ControlCollection col,string desiredID)
    {
        Control found=default(Control);


        if (found != null)
            return found;
            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
            {

                Control temp = col[i];
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    if (temp.ID != null)
                    {
                        if (temp.ID == desiredID)
                        {
                            found = temp;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (found != null)
                                return found;
                            else
                            found=FindControl2(temp.Controls, desiredID);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (found != null)
                            return found;
                        else
                        found = FindControl2(temp.Controls, desiredID);
                    }


                }
            }

        return found;
    }
```

I used this and it worked

thanks